# Can you add doubleclick macros to exisiting ads

Tags: advertising, google-dfp

**Setup:**
A few weeks back I made some very simple html5 "ads" to run on a few of our partner sites. They weren't paid ads as we also manage these sites, however there are a few of them, so I made a modular solution that is hosted on one of our web servers and included on each page via javascript which outputs an iframe. Each search (ad has a search box) or click appends a url param that we track using custom vars in Google Analytics.

*In essence, the ad is a HTML page served in an iframe via javscript.*

**Problem:**
We have an opportunity to run these ads on a third party site, I had sent them a brief how-to for inserting them and they came back saying that:

> The creative code doesn't contain the %u macro.  We can’t substitute the default click-through URL without it.

I am somewhat familiar with doubleclick from a  web developer's POV, i have inserted DC dart tags before and even have implemented the ad tool for publishers.

I have not, however, actually ever created an ad for the doubleclick network before. I assume the publisher needs these tags to track clicks and hence charge us. However, they have not responded to me in regards to these questions.

Are macros something I can just add to or replace the existing links with, or do I need to completely setup the ad with doubleclcik - a big issue in the short term given we do not have a advertiser's account set up with them.

Thanks in advance